# How to fix the problem in this XKCD comic?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, clustered-standard-errors

[image: Slope Hypothesis Testing]
[Slope Hypothesis Testing](https://xkcd.com/2533/) (Randall Munroe, *xkcd*)

---

The problem with this comic is obviously that the "measurements" are not independent, violating a key assumption for computing valid p-values. But I see also a possible problem with the fact that the dependent variable "grade" is constant for each student.

What is the correct way to analyze this data?

I've scraped the data and I've tried a random effects model but it wasn't clear how to specify the model structure. I got the best results so far by using the `lm.cluster` function from the `miceadds` package, and specifying each student as its own cluster. Still, I get a p-value of 0.12 which is far from the original p-value of 0.586.

[image: graph depicting grade/loudness points from the comic]

Reproducible example:

```r
pane3 <-
structure(list(loudness = c(86.23265220830784, 86.525433974655584, 
86.70530770034479, 86.885181426033995, 88.689627893786295, 88.892405630102843, 
89.049912682657435, 89.207285400838856, 92.147394659462378, 92.417541083929137, 
92.575182470856902, 92.709919847157337), grade = c(75.96108780990194, 
76.148932041733218, 76.064749167873202, 75.980566294013173, 93.944878128871437, 
94.130035673239107, 94.134737376300436, 94.049882830574518, 89.122721912921492, 
89.220338224099606, 89.314596175948196, 89.139513709569087), 
    student = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    loudness = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), grade = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"))

ggplot(pane3, aes(x = loudness, y = grade)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")

summary(lm(grade ~ loudness, pane3))

library(lme4)
summary(lmer(grade ~ loudness + (1 | student), pane3))

library(miceadds)
summary(lm.cluster(data = pane3, formula = grade ~ loudness, cluster = "student"))
```

Comment: You should not get the original value of 0.586 (even assuming that is correctly calculated). The new points are not independent but they do contain *some* information.

Comment: A further issue here is that collecting further observations conditionally on not observing significance violates standard test assumptions anyway. One would need a sequential protocol pre data for doing this, and the actual computations for testing would be quite different. So even better looking test results from better models should not be trusted as long as the data were collected in the shown way and the better model only adopted after drawing further data as consequence of insignificance.

Comment: *Do* you analyze these data?

Comment: The model in the comic is clear: *loudness,* conditional on grade, is what varies.  Use loudness, then, as the conditional response.

Comment: A "correct way" to analyze their data with their setup is with a measurement error model. The regression coefficients and their standard error can be consistently estimated when there are independent replicates of the covariate available, which is the case here. In contrast to @whubers interesting approach, the measurement error model permits measurement error in both the covariate and the response and also follows the same setup as on the left-most pane of the comic. (See section 3.4.2 in Carroll et al. Measurement Error...)

Answer (score 8):

"What is the correct way to analyze this data?"

There have been good answer suggesting analyses already. I'd like to add that there is no unique "correct" analysis of the data. For example, does it make sense to assume linearity given that the grade scale is limited? Obviously a linear model will be wrong, but then "all models are wrong but some are useful" - this one may or may not be useful, and an effective sample size of three (beyond which you don't go repeating observations for the three students) for sure is not enough to assess how good or harmful the linearity assumption actually is. One could do something like a logit transform of the exam (percentage) grades, and based on the fact that this at least produces the correct value range (unless people score 0 or 100, but this is easy to repair, if not in a uniquely correct manner) arguably this should be preferred, but once more the data do not allow to assess this in any detail. Furthermore, if we're talking about students from the same class, there may be dependence even between the students, for which there is no way to assess this from the data alone - and collecting more students from the same class won't help with that either.

So the baseline is that any analysis will require subjective decisions for or against which there may be arguments, in some way or another taking background knowledge into account that may go further than what we actually know (like grade distributions from earlier courses), but there is no formal "objective" way to decide between them (other than pointing out obvious flaws in certain analyses as the ignorance of dependence in the cartoon), and so there is no single "correct way" to analyse these (or any) data.

Comment: These are valid points, but for this toy example I was only wondering what was the correct approach for estimating the fixed effects of a linear model when the points are repeated, almost identical measures.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is composed of multiple questions/issues. I can answer the first one, the second is still unclear to me.

> summary(lmer(grade ~ loudness + (1 | student), pane3))

What happened here is that the mixed effects model is effectively fitting three lines that have different (random) intercepts, instead of a single line. This results in the following output for fixed effects

```
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   76.521     11.866   6.449
loudness       0.111      0.119   0.933
```

the slope of $\beta = 0.111$ instead of $\beta = 1.94$ is more like an effect within subjects rather than between subjects. It could be possible that the effect of loudness has an effect within subjects, and by measuring the subjects many times, you could observe a significant effect.

---

> summary(lm.cluster(data = pane3, formula = grade ~ loudness, cluster = "student"))

to be continued, it is not so clear what this method does, but giving a p-value of 0.12 is indeed weird

---

In addition you have a third question

> How to fix the problem in this XKCD comic?

You fix this by sampling more people.

Alternatively, you can sample the same people multiple times*. This *should* reduce the noise in the case that there is not only an error from person to person, but also within the persons. If you sample the same person multiple times then you get more accurate information about that average performance of that person, and you reduce the influence of the noise due to the same person potentially having different exam results.

In the first pane of the XKCD image, the results where highly variable. In the third pane it was still the same.

The XKCD comic, stages the situation where the exam grade is *not* much variable within the same person. (Or it is even the same because they seem to have only repeated the loudness measurements and the variations in exam grade are due to your data scraping).

That is *not* necessarily the case when some resampling is done. Consider the following

[image: example of different case]

Of course, it might be still doubtful whether inference with only three data points is a good idea. And possibly one should use a model that considers the error in the x-variable (like Deming regression). But the point is that repetitions within subjects can improve the accuracy of the estimates.

---

*In fact, this way might be even better, because it allows you to observe the within subject error and assess the goodness of fit. This is why scientists in quantitative fields like to perform duplicate or triplicate measurements.

Comment: Note that keeping the number of students at three and just collecting more data for every single student won't get your "effective sample size" for assessing the slope larger than three. In any analysis that pretends to get beyond this, this can only be achieved as a consequence of model assumptions that are untestable and should not be trusted.

Comment: Chances are for the model with a single random effect one can derive a lower bound of the variance of the slope estimator for three students with any number of replicates per student that should really at best be marginally lower than the variance based on a single observation, if at all, although I don't have the time to derive this.

Comment: Note in particular that the random effects model will *not* imply that if you observe infinitely many observations per student, the mean of those will be on the regression line. There is an irreducible random error of every student's mean that cannot be reduced by replicating observations from the same student.

Comment: @ChristianHennig , sure the effective random sample size will remain at least three (I thought that this was not so much the issue here) but the sampling occurs with a smaller amount of noise, and the power of the test should incease. It is possible to obtain more significant results by increasing the number of within subjects measurements.

Comment: I don't deny the qualitative statement that power could increase, however I believe that any potential increase is severely limited (I suspect that the best achievable estimator variance with sample size $n$ only should be by some fairly small constant lower than the one from only one replicate).

Comment: The comic is mocking the idea that we can increase the effective df or sample size by sampling the same people. But the question is about what this re-sampling is doing. Sure, the story from the comic is not right and we can't assume an increase of the effective sample size as if the measurements where all independent. On the other hand, the multiple sampling *can* improve the results. If we have multiple test scores per student,  and use an average (or apply a mixed effects model) then we are using a larger amount of information and should be able to obtain an estimate with less variance.

Comment: *"I believe that any potential increase is severely limited"* Maybe for the case of three individuals, but when the size is larger, then it might become beneficial to resample the same individuals instead of finding new individuals. That would be the case if resampling the same individual is cheaper than sampling a new individual.

Comment: @ChristianHennig https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606535/optimize-the-number-of-individuals-inside-a-sample

Comment: This is an inappropriate model, because the grades are not independently measured: *they are perfectly dependent.*  (They were simply repeated, not remeasured.)  Consider modeling the loudness conditional on grades instead.

Comment: @whuber Yes, in the XKCD comic the resampling makes no sense. But that doesn't mean that it never makes sense in other situations (because of that I made a sketch of a different potential situation where grades are not perfectly dependent and differ within the same subject). I believe that the question is asking for those situations where it does make sense, and asks for how we have to deal with the problem in those situations (like how to consider the degrees of freedom).

Comment: I see now that the comic speaks about only the yelling being repeated but not the exam. In the given data this is not the case and the exam results differs as well.

Comment: I disagree.  The resampling makes perfect sense.  The problem is that you are modeling it incorrectly.  The grade is not resampled: it is a constant characteristic of each subject.  The loudness is being repeatedly measured.

Comment: @whuber I am just taking the model of the OP as the starting point and the data that is supplied clearly indicates that the grade is not constant for the resampled points. That this is not the idea of the XKCD image, I agree, but then the question should be closed for being unclear.

Comment: The grade is not constant due to measurement errors in scraping the Web graphic.  The original comic and its text make it clear that the grades are just repeated: *that's the entire point of the comic!*

Comment: @whuber but is the point of the question the same as the point of the comic? To me this was (and is still) not clear and I answered the question with a different interpretation of the question. I agree that the application of such models is wrong for the XKCD image, but not in general for different situations.

Comment: I understand the phrase "obviously that the "measurements" are not independent" as keying in on the fact the repeated grades are as non-independent as one can possibly get!

Comment: @whuber Yes, the measurements are not independent, but when you understand that as *fully* dependent then this is *your* interpretation. That's however not consistent with the *entire* question, which adds a dataset that is the opposite to a fully dependent situation, and diverges from the XKCD comic. Anyway, I don't get so much the criticism to my answer. Criticise the question instead. I am just giving an answer to a specific interpretation. You seem to be turning this into a wrong answer to a different question, but that is more a semantic discussion about the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with the nlme or lme4 packaes easily, all you have to add is a random effect for the students (and slope).

```
> library(nlme)
> summary(lme(grade~loudness,random=~1|student/loudness,data=pane3))
    ...
Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | student
        (Intercept)
StdDev:    9.131586

 Formula: ~1 | loudness %in% student
        (Intercept)   Residual
StdDev:  0.04725001 0.07510526

Fixed effects: grade ~ loudness 
               Value Std.Error DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 76.52081 11.866096  8 6.448693  0.0002
loudness     0.11097  0.118994  8 0.932552  0.3783
    ...
```

loudness not significant.

Comment: Too few groups for a random effect to be a good idea, I would think.

Comment: Can you explain why the coefficient from the mixed model is so much lower than the coefficient from the linear model with 3 points?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva This is just some toy data, made up, it is not the original data from the comic and we do not even know if the results reported there are real, so take these values with 100% salt.

Comment: They are real, I've reproduced them, but I don't understand what the mixed model is doing here.  The mixed model result is nowhere close to what the linear model with just the three points would show. It's closer to a fixed effects linear model `lm(data=pane3 , grade ~ loudness + student)` so I wondered if you had any insight into why.  Like you my intuition was that `lmer` should recover the original model but it doesn't.  It's as if its reporting a 'within cluster' effect whereas we want the 'between cluster' effect, or something!

Comment: @GeorgeSavva The mixed model is still estimating a slope coefficient, but it is doing so while "stratifying" for students, you can image each student gets its own slope, and these slopes are then combined to get the final slope, so it is similar to what a linear model is doing (except that the students are not fixed). And since on a student level the slope is very close to zero, then the final coefficient is also close to zero.

Comment: Right, so in this case the mixed model is *not* doing what OP wants, which is to reproduce the correct `lm` fit *between* students

Comment: @GeorgeSavva I think it is, OP is asking how to correctly analyse these results using a mixed model, as I understand.

Comment: +1. In fairness even if we fit the silly model `lm(grade ~ loudness + student, data = pane3)` the coefficient of `loudness` is insignificant.

Comment: @mkt "Too few groups for a random effect to be a good idea, I would think." So what would be your alternative (other than collecting a larger sample)? I don't see any better idea than that.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Clustered standard errors?

Comment: @mkt Fair enough as idea, even though 3 clusters isn't exactly a recommended number either.

Comment: @user2974951 I think @GeorgeSavva has a point; the mixed model with the `~1|student/loudness` term, I believe, lets each student have their own slope, which is going to be close to 0 since each student has a single value for their grade.

I suppose I could have rephrased my question as follows: if the data in pane 3 of the comic was your experimental result, how would you analyze it to find any relationship between grade and loudness? I mentioned mixed model because it was the first thing that came to mind but are there other approaches?

Comment: @lindelof If you have only the original data, that is 3 points and no repeated measurements, then there is no mixed modelling, you can at best use a linear model. But the core issue is an issue of sample size and not an issue of which model to use, you will get very uncertain results with only 3 units in your sample, regardless of model. So the answer is "get more data".